# Where do resource files go within Onion Architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design, embedded-resource, resx, onion-architecture

2 part question... I have several resource files (.resx) used in my solution primarily for translation of strings. For example, Errors.resx, Validation.resx, and Enums.resx.

**Part1** : If I didn't have the Enums resource file, I'd assume that I should place all resource files in the UI Layer, probably within it's own assembly (like 'Company.App1.MVCApp.Resources') and reference it from the web app (Company.App1.MVCApp)... would I be correct in placing the resource files in the UI layer?

**Part 2**: The Enums.resx file contains descriptive strings that tie to enum members (using the Description attribute), in my UI and sometimes Domain services I will need to access the descriptive strings possibly in their translation. I thought about storing this somewhere in the Core/Domain layer maybe somewhere like Company.App1.Core.Resources ...  ? Or should I create an abstraction in the Core layer and then implement the ResourcemManager somewhere in the Infrastructure layer in order to stick to the proper Onion Architecture.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Part1** : In the application I'm currently working on, there isn't one resx file per concern (Enums, Errors...) but one resx file per project. If you take error messages, for instance, purely UI error messages go in the UI resx file, domain error messages go in the Domain resx, and son on. IMO resource files are best placed closest to the code where the localized strings are used. Having most localization files in the UI project tightly couples localization to the way your application is rendered, which might be problematic if you want to reuse localization in another context than that of your main UI.

**Part2** : If you only need to access localized enum members in the Domain layer, then you could have a specific helper in the domain layer that derives from or uses `System.Resources.ResourceManager` to find the localized string. However, I find it handy to have some kind of general-purpose localization helper in an independent layer that centralizes all the localization logic that is more complex than just a `Properties.Resources.[...]` and is able to search in all resx files of your solution if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the info... actually, creating the "helper" you referred to makes a lot of sense. I guess it'd be a factory of a sort, could I make use of DI? There's already a ResourceProviderFactory but it lives in System.Web.Compilation so I'd imagine I'd write my own implementation in my app's Core/Domain and then make use of System.Web.Compilation.ResourceProviderFactory in the infrastructure layer... yes?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a Factory if it just returns localized strings. My point was to have a unique service or helper containing all your localization-related utility methods such as GetLocalizedEnumMember(...) and the like. I'm not sure why you'd want multiple implementations of your ResourceProvider ?

Comment: well to allow the flexibility of storing localized data in the database in the future... like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4647571/1240322

Comment: He's talking about one concrete implementation for each message data store (SQL, etc.) while you only seem to have resx files. Also, Factories are usually used when you have an unknown number of objects you want to build at runtime. If I get you right, you'd want a Factory that creates ResourceProviders. But isn't the number of ResourceProviders you need well known in advance ? Wouldn't a compile-time definition of the types of ResourceProviders be good enough (YAGNI principle) ?

Comment: I guess my concern is what if we decide to stop using resx files and store all localized strings in the database one day? or (less likely) send off to a web service to translate strings not localized to a certain language and then store in database. I think you're right, factory wouldnt apply here but maybe DI? If I understand the principles of Onion architecture correctly, I'd want this complexity pushed outwards towards the infrastructure layer meaning I'd need an interface in the Core to not be tied to an implementation (ResourceManager). or am I way off?

Comment: Sure you could do that if you want. You could have an abstract ResourceManager and inject concrete implementations of it using DI. It could help you with unit tests as well, passing a fake implementation. However, since multiple layers can use a ResourceManager, I wouldn't put the abstraction in the Core/Domain but somewhere it can be accessed by everyone (a utility/helpers layer) otherwise it means that everyone has to reference the Core.

Comment: Thank you! This brings another question to mind, isn't everything supposed to reference core? If core is where all domain entities and interfaces are, isn't that how onion works? I'd implement this to it's own assembly but wouldn't it logically belong to the "Core layer" ?  i.e. Company.App1.Core.ResourceUtils that references Core because interface for it is there?

Comment: Not necessarily, for instance you could have a UI that doesn't reference the Domain to prevent coupling. From the original Onion Architecture article : "The outer layer is reserved for things that change often.  These things should be intentionally isolated from the application core." Besides, returning localized strings doesn't seem to me like a Domain concern at all, it's more of a cross-cutting concern like logging, error handling... It's probably a better idea to place this kind of logic in a separate module you'll be able to reuse in other applications regardless of their domain...