# What is a good way to get resource strings to a class in a dependency injection world?

Tags: c#, winforms, dependency-injection, embedded-resource

I am working on a new application that may have some internationalization requirements in the future. I am looking at using a resource file for the string information.  I am also working on making the application testable.

Is there a built-in .Net interface to use to pass a class with the resource file ready to use or do I roll my own?

I'm assuming that I should not allow the class to go get it itself. In this case it is for an exception message, but I don't think it matters.

Comment: We rolled our own and create interfaces for each batch of logical resource we want to expose via factories (which determine the resource to return, either given locale or client). The consuming classes then just take or ask for an `IFormStrings` or whatever. I don't know of anything built in, but it is possible to replace the resx code gen tool, but not always trivial to do so.

Comment: Is this app being built with MVC or WPF or is it WebForms or WinForms? Localization with resource files is more seamless with the newer development models.

Comment: @jfrankcarr - It is a Winforms app

Comment: @RichShealer - Roll your own is probably the way to go or you could use a DI framework. It also might be good to look at how MVC and WPF generate their resource and localization classes and see what you can take from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localization using a DI framework - good idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646848/localization-using-a-di-framework-good-idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question addresses the issues I was facing in my question above.

[#4646848 Localization using a di framework good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646848/localization-using-a-di-framework-good-idea)